# Will function g has derivative at x=c?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose there is function $f, g, h$ where $h(x)=f(x).g(x)$ for all $x$. If $f(c), f'(c), g(c), h'(c)$ exist and $f(c)\neq0$. Does $g'(c)$ exist?

Answer (score 0):

For $x$ near $c$, and since $f(c)\neq 0$,

we can define $$g(x)=\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}$$

and

$$g'(c)=\frac{h'(c)f(c)-g(c)f(c)f'(c)}{(f(c))^2}.$$